# Full width page divs

Tags: css, html, width

I'm designing a website, I'm trying to get a simple coloured div across the top of the browser, I've tried simply using:

```
div{
    width:100%;
}
```

but noticed there's white space on either side and on top of the screen.

I'm looking for something similar to the blue header on Facebook that fills the entire screen.

Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Comment: use firebug and you can solve yourself. Because CSS will keep on troubling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is always some margin and padding in all browsers for the `body`. So, try doing the following and recheck the results:-

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

The above code will remove all the extra margins and paddings from all the tags!

You should use [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) for a kick-start designing of your applications though.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the default margin and padding thanks for the info!

Comment: Upvoting because you are only 13

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yeah, thanks. I started coding since I was 10 years old.

Answer (score 2):

did the body have margin?

Try adding:

```
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

or use a reset for styles like: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 1):

It's because of default styles of your browser, use this to reset it:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VmgHt/)**

Besides that, I'd suggest you take a look at [css reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) which give you a set of CSS rules that resets the styling of all HTML elements to a consistent baseline.